# HTML5 + PHP + JS para android

Tags: php, javascript, html5, ionic, intel-xdk

tenho uma página em html + js+ php que utiliza do navigator.geolocation, funciona perfeitamente no navegador, porém, estou efetuando uns testes e gostaria de "transformar" esta página para um apk

Utilizei o xdk e o ionic, porém quando o apk é construído parece que as função JS não funciona ou o mesmo não consegue acessar o GPS do dispositivo, mesmo funcionando no navegador.

Alguém tem uma solução pra isso ?

Grato.

Comment: Já testou na aba "Debug" do intel-xdk para ver se da algum erro?

Comment: Sim, não dá erro.... nem no xdk nem no ionic

Comment: Você adicionou o plugin cordova-plugin-geolocation? e se adicionou foi na mão ou pelo xdk? quando add pelo xdk ela já coloca as permissões que precisa, verifica se estão setadas.

Comment: @AndréVicente , adicionei pelo xdk mesmo, o código que uso pra obter a localização é bem parecido com esse aqui

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation

Comment: O php não funciona dentro do aplicativo, ionic, phonegap, xdk, so leem js, html e css, o o que você pode fazer é procurar plugin de geolocation para ionic

Comment: O php funciona somente no servidor, tente enviar o php para um servidor, e chamar por ajax, deve resolver o problema.

Comment: Talvez você vai ter que usar API do próprio PhoneGap ou XDK pra isso